# pick latest date of each item and get the sum in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a requirement where there are 10 items for each item there are 10 records that has `buy price` and `sell price`.

Now my requirement is to for each item I need to take the latest date and calculate the buy and sell price... in the same way I need to do for all 10 items and finally sum the buy and sell of all items to get the overall sum... I need to do this whole thing in a single query..

I can write queries and sub queries but have no idea on how to write such a complex query..

Data as:

```
item    date        buy    sell

item1   28/10/2014  10      10
item1   27/10/2014  10      10
item1   26/10/2014  10      10
item2   28/10/2014  10      10
item2   27/10/2014  10      10
item2   26/10/2014  10      10
item3   28/10/2014  10      10
item3   27/10/2014  10      10
item3   26/10/2014  10      10
```

my rewuirment is to get

```
item1   28/10/2014  10      10
item2   28/10/2014  10      10
item3   28/10/2014  10      10
```

and finally `totay buy=30` and `total sell=30`

What I have tried till now:

below query I have tried

```
select item as c, buy as a ,sell as b,date from table group by item order by  substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,4,2) ||substr(date,1,2) desc limit 1
```

This query returning value of only one 1 row corresponding to one item not 3 rows. I am not sure how to construct these kind of queries.

Comment: I don't understand why total sell is 20

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 I apologize total sell should be 30.. updated my question

Comment: try to check the answer below

Comment: Why don't you use one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)?

Comment: @CL. Thanks for your response I have achieved using `date` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the query which I have achieved using `date` function of `sqlite`.

```
select item as c, buy_qua as a ,buy_price as b,max(date( substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2) ||'-'||substr(date,1,2))) as e from table group by item order by e desc
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the `max(date)` instead of using `limit 1`, and you can just `sum` the `buy` and `sell` value as usual:

```
select item as c, buy as a, sell as b, max(date), sum(buy) as totalbuy, sum(sell) as totalsell
from trans
group by item
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ef07f/14

**EDIT**:

per its documentation, `max` can be used for string as well.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html; it might also have single or multiple arguments.

Comment: Thnanks for your response... but my date is a string value... max is not working

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... but using `date` function I have achieved... +1 for the support

Answer (score 0):

You are using `select item as c, buy as a ,sell as b,date from table group by item order by  substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,4,2) ||substr(date,1,2) desc limit 1`

remove `limit 1`

So now your final query will be:

```
select item as c, buy_qua as a ,buy_price as b,max(date( substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2) ||'-'||substr(date,1,2))) as e from table group by item order by e desc
```

Comment: thanks for your response if I remove the `limit1` then I am not getting latest date for the items..

Comment: `Limit` actually limits the number of result records to be displayed, refer this [link](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-limit.html) i dont think `limit` is linked to `getting latest date for the items`